# Convert complex JSON to JAVA Object where different keys are to be converted into the same type of object

Tags: java, json

I would like to convert a complex JSON into a Java Object. My problem is that "child1" and "child2" contain the same information.

I haven't found a solution to **automatically detect** child1 and child2 when converting a JSON file and generate them from a single object. In my current solution the child's always have to be stored manually in the class.

Here's the JSON file:

```
{
   "certs":[
      "cert1",
      "cert2"
   ],
   "parent":{
      "child01":{
         "prop1":"value1",
         "prop2":[
            "value1"
         ],
         "prop3":[
            "value1"
         ]
      },
      "child02":{
         "prop1":"value1",
         "prop2":[
            "value1"
         ],
         "prop3":[
            "value1"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the class for the parent:

```
  public class Application {
  ArrayList<Object> certs = new ArrayList<Object>();
  Parent ParentObject;


 // Getter Methods 

  public Parent getParent() {
    return ParentObject;
  }

 // Setter Methods 

  public void setParent( Parent parentObject ) {
    this.ParentObject = parentObject;
  }
}
```

Here is the class that creates an object for each child:

```
public class Parent {
  Child1 Child1Object;
  Child2 Child2Object;


 // Getter Methods 

  public Child1 getChild1() {
    return Child1Object;
  }

  public Child2 getChild2() {
    return Child2Object;
  }

 // Setter Methods 

  public void setChild1( Child1 child1Object ) {
    this.Child1Object = child1Object;
  }

  public void setChild2( Child2 child2Object ) {
    this.Child2Object = child2Object;
  }
}
public class Child2 {
  private String prop1;
  ArrayList<Object> prop2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
  ArrayList<Object> prop3 = new ArrayList<Object>();


 // Getter Methods 

  public String getProp1() {
    return prop1;
  }

 // Setter Methods 

  public void setProp1( String prop1 ) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
}
```

Here is the class for the child's:

```
public class Child1 {
  private String prop1;
  ArrayList<Object> prop2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
  ArrayList<Object> prop3 = new ArrayList<Object>();


 // Getter Methods 

  public String getProp1() {
    return prop1;
  }

 // Setter Methods 

  public void setProp1( String prop1 ) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
}
```

I would like to not specify each object individually in the parent class, because it would mean that if the JSON file extends with new child's, I would have to manually extend the class with the child names each time.

When I convert the JSON file, the child's should be recognized automatically and for each child an object with the name of the child (child1, child2) should be generated without manually entering the names "child1" and "child2" in the parent class.

Comment: You should put `child1`, `child2` in an array (`children`)

Answer (score 0):

You should never have repetitive entries of the exact same object, you should expect a list (or other form of collection) of said objects, since it's always extensible, and it fits any scenario

Comment: The problem is that in the JSON file the entries "child01" and "child02" have the same structure, but different names.

i would like gson to generate multiple objects or a list of objects without manually specifying each name (child01 or child02) in the parent class.

Comment: In that case the only solution i can think of is implementing a custom deserializer for parent in which you will obtain each child node and serialize it into a collection